# Personal builds (pre-test commits) using TFS and Jenkins

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to trigger personal builds using TFS and Jenkins? Similar to what can be achieved using Teamcity. Can a developer trigger a build without checking-in so that his/her changes can be tested before checkin?
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with TFS. Assuming you are using TFS Build, available in TFS 2015 and in VSTS, and your source control is Git, you can setup a build policy for a specific branch that triggers a build any time a pull request happens. Details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/code/git/branch-policies).

If you are using the older XAML builds, look at Gated Checkins.